# Windows 10 crazy slow for no reason

Tags: windows-10

I am running `Windows 10 21H2 OS Build 19044.1826` on a fast PC. My specs are as follows:

```
Processor:   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz   2.10 GHz
RAM:         64.0 GB (63.8 GB usable)
System type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
```

Up until about 2 weeks ago this PC was always blazing fast. And then suddenly it started running slow. REALLY slow. I don't know what changed around that time. I sometimes install new apps, but I don't remember if I installed anything new around that time - certainly nothing major.

For example, dragging a simple windows explorer window across the screen became laggy. And typing an address in Chrome became laggy and choppy. Scrolling up and down in Chrome became slow and laggy. Switching between open apps (ALT+TAB) is slow, takes a few seconds. When these symptoms occur you should expect to go into Task Manager and see something churning at 99% CPU and maybe all the RAM maxed out. But nothing of the kind is happening:

[image]

[image]

There is plenty of space on C:

[image]

Additionally, there is plenty of space remaining on all drives.

Here is what my system looked like about 15 seconds after running Prime95:

[image]

After another 15 seconds it was using 99% of CPU and memory.

I have rebooted multiple times in the past few weeks. Even when no apps are running, it's slow all the time.

I can't help but think that Task Manager is lying to me. There must be something consuming lots of CPQ, but it says the opposite. **How can I find the source of the slowness?**

Comment: What happens if you stress the CPU deliberately (Prime95 or the like), does it go to its specified clock of 2.1 GHz?

Comment: How much disk space do you have left?

Comment: Try an Offline Scan with Windows Defender.

Comment: I concur with @Gantendo here. An SSD with too little diskspace left, especially on the C drive can bring a system on its knees.

Comment: There is plenty of space on C and on all drives. I edited the original question to show this. I'll try to stress the CPQ and I'll try an offline scan. Thanks all, please keep in touch with this post.